# How do I show that a loopless graph contains a spanning graph with certain properties?

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that any loopless graph $ G $ contains a spanning bipartite subgraph $ F $, in which the degree of any vertex $ x $  is greater than or equal to $ \deg (x) / 2 $, where $ \deg (x) $ is the degree of $ x $ in the original graph.

By induction it does not work out somehow

There is also an idea that a graph is bipartite if it does not have cycles of odd length and come up with some algorithm for removing edges from cycles, but it turns out something confusing, you can't see how to prove it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your attempt at proof by induction?  Your second run on sentence is meaningless, unless you show us your effort to prove by induction, and what you did that "turns out something confusing".

Answer (score 1):

Color the vertices of your graph $\color{red}{red}$ or $\color{blue}{blue}$ in such a way that maximizes the number of edges with extremes $\color{red}{red}$ and $\color{blue}{blue}$.

Consider now the spanning subgraph with every edge with extremes $\color{red}{red}$ and $\color{blue}{blue}$. Of course it's bipartite, because it connects only vertices of different colors. Also, if the degree of a vertex $x$ in this new graph was less than $\deg(x)/2$, switching the color of $x$ would increase the number of edges with extremes $\color{red}{red}$ and $\color{blue}{blue}$ in the original graph, contradicting it's maximality. Therefore, this spanning subgraph has the desired proprieties.